# where i can get blacklist spam email domain dataset?

Tags: email, dns, dataset, spam, blacklist

I wanna create an email classifier
the classifier will be divide by email, subject, content classifier

for email classifier, I need a list of blacklist domain such as @blablabla.com @cacacaca.com etc.

like this set [here](http://www.joewein.de/sw/blacklist.htm)

but I need an up to date domain, so where I can get them? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if a good way might be to go to mxtoolbox, do a blacklist test, then get a list of blacklist sites and see if you can contact them to get a list?

I suspect that such companies may consider those datasets their intellectual property and probably won't publish these - it may not be possible.

Good luck!

Also Akismet may have such a dataset?

Additionally, the more powerful email classifying software works by using patterns that you can make. Check out MailMarshall88 for example. You could use this to build your own dataset, but remember that just because someone is on a blacklist today, doesn't mean that they're always bad. For example, you might get a virus outbreak in your company which spams people and gets your IP blacklisted. You then fix the virus and are now incorrectly blacklisted. In this scenario a pattern would work much better.